# Add a question mark before postname in permalink structure(WP

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress post url like

http://www.mywpblog.com/firstpost

Now I would like to change it to

http://www.mywpblog.com/?firstpost

Is it possible via htaccess or any wp tricks.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: do you want to change the link so that people see /?firstpost instead of /firstpost ?

Comment: then you will need to add a rule to your htacces wich redirect /?firstpost to /firstpost, **AND**, more importantly, you will need to change all you /firstpost links in your pages to /?firstpost manualy (most people think that the htacces file will do this too)

Comment: Actually I have to do the opposite.Now the links in href are /firstpost which is ok now when the user click that link it will redirect to /?firstpost...and I should see the /?firstpost in the url...

Comment: Ok I wrote an answer, but it is only for firstpost (is firstpost a variable ?)

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: firstpost is the name of the post....in wordpress the permalink structure is /%postname%/ ...and I tried by changing it to /?%postname%/ but it couldn't recognize the post and brings the same page.Let me try with your suggestion.

Comment: I edited my answer (%postname% and suc hthings will only work inside php not in htaccess)

Comment: It's not working.I have edited the default wordpress htaccess and at the end of the line I have added the above code.

Comment: I don't know the default code of WP but maybe it is conflicting with the above code, add this code before the WP code

Comment: http://blog.xxx.com/?/category/muay-thai/

Now the url looks like this and it's showing the index page content which is from http://blog.xxx.com...this url is ok for me but don't know why wp is not showing the right content.